# QML Rotated Image not Filling Container

Tags: image, qt, qml, scaling

I am working with QML to try to display an image. I have the following code:

```
Rectangle {
  id: border
  anchors {
    top: parent.top; 
    topMargin: vpx(20); 
    right: parent.right;
  }
  color: "black"
  z: 6
  width: 500
  height: 750
            
  Image {
    id: picture
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    transformOrigin: Item.Center
    rotation: (implicitWidth/implicitHeight > 1.3) ? 270 : 0
    anchors.fill: border
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    source: ".../pic.png"
  }
```

If rotation is set to 0, it scales correctly to fill the rectangle. If rotation is set to 270, it doesn't fill the rectangle - it rotates correctly, but it is well within the rectangle in both directions. It should have scaled up more.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: The code above has been edited. All of the above code is within a larger rectangle. The purpose of this code is to rotate images 90 degrees when they have a width > height. When rotation is set to 0 (i.e. height > width and no rotation needed), the picture displays as the first case below. When set to 270 (i.e. width > height, rotation needed), the picture displays as the second case below. I would like it to be comparable to the first picture, which fills the width, as I understand "fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit" should work.

black is rectangle, red is the image.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your issue, i.e. the context of the `Rectangle` and what exactly do you mean by _it is well within the rectangle in both directions_? I was trying to reproduce your issue but without any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of tricky, but you can try this way:

```
Rectangle {
    id: border
    anchors {
        top: parent.top;
        right: parent.right;
    }
    color: "black"
    z: 6
    width: 500
    height: 750

    Item {
        id: pictureItem
        transformOrigin: Item.Center
        rotation: (picture.implicitWidth/picture.implicitHeight > 1.3) ? 270 : 0
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: rotation == 270 ? parent.height : parent.width
        height: rotation == 270 ? parent.width : parent.height

        Image {
            id: picture
            anchors.fill: parent
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: ".../pic.png"
        }
    }
}
```

I have prepared two test images:

[image: Test image 1]

[image: Test image 2]

And this is what I get with above chunk of code:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Couple questions though. Since the rectangle was just as a placeholder, can I just remove it and use the item for this purpose? Why is the item needed? I tried using this same approach, but with just an image within a rectangle, and it didn't work (i.e. defining width and height conditionally, based on rotation, within the image rather than the item). How come?

Comment: It depends apparently on properties precedence. An image is firstly fit to given dimension and then rotated. Besides, this is what Qt documentation says about `paintedHeight` and `paintedWidth` of QML `Image`: _These properties hold the size of the image that is actually painted. In most cases it is the same as width and height, but when using an Image.PreserveAspectFit or an Image.PreserveAspectCrop paintedWidth or paintedHeight can be smaller or larger than width and height of the Image item._ https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedHeight-prop